# Returning duplicate entries

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have a table with _id,name. I use SQLite3 queries to fetch names given id, like the following api.

```
getName(id) >> Query "select name from table where _id=id"
```

and this other handy API for an array of IDs, the returned rows (names) must match the order of requested IDs.

```
getNames(ids) >> 
    /* Returned text must be ordered */
    var ordClause='ORDER BY CASE _id';
    for(var i=1;i<=ids.length;i++){ ordClause += ' WHEN '+ids[i-1]+' THEN '+i; }
    ordClause += ' END';
    Query "select name from table where _id in( "+ids+" ) "+ordClause
```

The problem appears when the given `ids` have duplicate values. Redundant ids are mapped to the first id only. Thus the returned rows may be less than the requested IDs.

How can I possibly solve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate IDs are just annoying. With a big DB it would take lots of time to execute, but I would dump all the data into a new table structure with a new unique ID field and keep the old_ids as provisional reference. I'm not sure this is a good idea in your case...

Comment: My approach could be the  worst if the amount of data is too massive...

Comment: Actually the data is too big for this solution, and the redundant situation is very rare, very very few API calls have redundant ids in corner use cases. I should smartly find a solution for this special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SELECT query returns any row that matches the filter in the WHERE clause.
Redundant IDs in the IN set do not change the fact that a single row matches that filter.

If you actually want duplicate rows, you have to write a separate query for each of them:

```
SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 7
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 8
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 8
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 7
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 1;
```

Comment: correct "ORDER BY never removes rows" but select in (list_with_redundancies) does. Maybe this is the root cause to tackle.

Comment: `IN (...)` does not remove matching rows either.

Comment: `select name from table where _id in( 7,8,8,7,1)` returns 3 rows only.

Comment: Thanks, your update works perfectly. What about the performace?

Comment: Would you rather have a faster query that does not return the correct result? ;-)